# Lamp and dimmer installation

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch, lamp

I'm currently installing a HALO LED SLD405930WHR (EATON)  i bought the Lutron CL dimmer SCL153PRWH which is compatible according to EATON website.
The HALO LED has 2 cables white and black, the jbox has 3 cables: white, red and black. I use a test pen and black is voltage.
When i plug HALO LED black cable to jbox black and HALO LED white cable to jbox white and there is no dimmer installed (dimmer socket cables not connected) HALO LED goes on. 
As soon as i connect the dimmer, the dimmer burns and there is a short circuit. The dimmer socket has 2 cables black and red. [image]
Not sure which cables to use in the lamp or dimmer.[image]

My guess is that lamp should be using jbox black and red[image] and same as dimmer. Will use a new dimmer, but want to check which one to use before i burn them.

Comment: How did you try to connect the dimmer?

Comment: I tried using 2 dimmers a) first combination: red and black dimmer cables' to red and black socket respectively b) red&white and black dimmer cables to red and black socket respectively, both times it burned. When i did both tests the lamp was connected to black and  white to black and white jbox

Comment: In the first try, what did you do with the red/white wire?

Comment: Nothing, just cover it with a cap. I connect the green dimmer cable to ground

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial? http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Education-Training/Pages/Tools/InstallDimmer.aspx#!/start/home?id=0&p=0

Comment: What do you mean by the dimmer "burning" BTW? Are you saying that it overheats/smoke (or the smell thereof) escapes? Or are you trying to say that it doesn't work?

Comment: There is a strong burn smells and sparks in second test

Comment: In the first two tries, what was the red wire in the ceiling j-box doing?

Comment: Connected to ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dimmers don't like shorting

The dimmer indeed should be black to black and red to red, with green to the grounds and the red/white striped wire capped off.  The light fixture though needs to go from wall box *red* to fixture black and wall box white to fixture white, with the grounds connected and the black wire in the fixture box capped off.

Connecting the light to black and red won't work because there's no return path for the current (i.e. no connection to neutral).  Your dimmer burnt because you grounded its output (the red wire) -- you should *never* ground a wire you don't know what to do with.  Cap it off by itself instead if in doubt.

Comment: Thank you if i understand correctly led will use only one cable white which will connect to red fixture. Black (voltage) in both fixture and lamp remain unconnected?

Comment: @spicyramen -- clarified the answer for you